# Voltage Based Current Limiting Application

Tags: resistors, diodes

I have a mobile application where I need to pre-charge the capacitors in a Victron 24v MultiPlus with a resistor before closing the circuit switch to its battery bank (24V 200Ah lithium); this prevents current inrush that would otherwise trip the battery management system on the batteries.

The concern is that when the pre-charge circuit is being used, even momentarily, I have a downstream device on the other side of a 24v-12v buck converter that behaves strangely due to the unexpectedly low rise in voltage, i.e. a radio that decides it isn't going to give me a display until I cycle the circuit while connected to shore power (which defeats the whole purpose of the pre-charge circuit I built). However I am additionally concerned that this happening repeatedly over time might damage those downstream components across the board.

What I think I need is something like a relay or a Schottky diode to prevent any current from going downstream until the voltage is high enough (~22V... needs to be a value slightly lower than what the system itself considers a 0% charge level) for downstream devices to remain healthy, but am not sure about the ratings requirements for such a relay or diode to achieve my goal. Or maybe I need something completely different?

Attached is a rough circuit diagram of my application.

[image]

EDIT: So ultimately I decided to go with a switch between the load and the rest of the power system. Added a bit more detail to the entire wiring diagram.

[image]

Comment: How many amps can your battery deliver at once? It's a lead-acid battery, I assume? That would help determine what you need.

Comment: It’s a 200Ah bank of 24V lithium batteries. So the inrush current it can produce is insanely high. The BMS will trip if I don’t use the precharge circuit I built.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, doesn't the panel have switches for each load, like the radio? Can't you recover the radio by cycling the power switch at the panel? And wouldn't a temporary work-around be to just turn everything off at the panel until you have done your pre-charge? Then turn everything you need on, one-by-one? The panel definitely needs either fuses or circuit breakers per circuit leading away from the panel.

Comment: @mkeith This particular iRV device has 3 power settings, on, mute, and standby. Yes, I would have zero issues if it had a hard off switch, alas! All the other 12V components do have hard switches so I have no issues there. There is a combination of breakers and fuses in the panel. It's really just a poorly designed radio/dvd unit

Comment: I was envisioning a switch on the panel labelled "radio" that goes only to the radio. No such luck I guess.

Comment: I see a "not precharge" main switch on the 24V line. Perhaps change it to a double-pole switch, and use the extra pole to switch the connection to the 24V-12V converter? So that it is not connected until you flip the main switch?

Comment: @user253751 that is exactly what I am going to do. See my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are 4 position battery switches that will serve the purpose. The [1, 1&2, 2, off] type. Position 1 MultiPlus + Battery, position 2 MultiPlus + 12V panel, so 1&2 for full closed circuit. This will solve the issue.

In the off position everything is isolated while the MultiPlus pre-charges, then in position 1 the batteries and MultiPlus are a fully closed circuit while the 12V panel is still isolated, then in the 1&2 position the entire system is a closed circuit and everything should be happy. Lot of work for a single stupid component, however I bet other 12V things like the refrigerator and thermostat (in heating mode) will be happier as well.

Note: I meant to make this a comment on somebody else’s post but they deleted it. However, it would still be super awesome to come up with an automated way of doing this with a relay or other smarter setup.

Comment: I deleted my post because it was wrong. if the multiplus fails having a way to run the DC loads off the battery with the multiplus out of circuit could save your life. and this answer provides that.

Comment: If you look at my diagram you see that isn’t a problem

Comment: what I meant was that was a problem in my answer. yours is correct.

Comment: Ok, understood. I am still not going to accept my own answer since it doesn't solve the problem the way I'd ultimately like to. Using the switch will sort of be a work around until I can master relay/diode setups.

Comment: @reka18 The whole pre-charge thing only happens when you are turning a switch *already*, right?

Comment: No, I have the precharge circuit contacted with a push button switch. Basically I push that for a few seconds and then I turn the main battery switch. No inrush.

Answer (score 2):

[Backfeed breakers](https://www.electricgeneratorsdirect.com/Generac-6852/p17598.html) exist. They're expensive, but can be switched back on when tripped, whereas a diode will blow with too much current and must be replaced.

That being said, a Schottky diode [similar to this one](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay-Semiconductors/VS-12F100M?qs=asPD7ZL2j3X0efSBVe2stg%3D%3D&mgh=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwxtSSBhDYARIsAEn0thSlbQESwClmfNiPIFfFyq_Nr7hnaNpCtpixW51EHzLMCJvOgAxOZe0aAhkDEALw_wcB) should work fine. Just make sure the diode has an amp tolerance greater than your 12v panel's main breaker or you could blow the diode. [The NEC recommends 125%](https://www.productinfo.schneider-electric.com/na-std-ref/5c0fee4b347bdf0001de4d55/Conductor%20Ampacity%20Tables/English/Data%20Bulletin%20-%20Conductor%20Ampacity%20Tables%20(bookmap)_0000264293.ditamap/$/NECInformationOfNote-F20BDBCC), but that may be more than enough.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think the forward amperage on that is too low though. I’ll need to add up the worst case scenario max amperage I might expect if all the 12v things got turned on at once.

Comment: I kept reading up on Schottky diodes and I am unclear as to if that is even a viable option. Seems they are used to rectify AC current to DC or prevent back current in various applications. What I was hoping for was a kind of diode that only allowed current to flow if the voltage was above a specific threshold based on the diode's rating.

Comment: @reka18 Sorry, I was under the impression you wanted to protect your equipment from any backfeed that could happen from disconnecting the charging circuit. I'll have to do some more research, but now it sounds like you might need a different solution.

Comment: Yeah I am going with switches to isolate the components at each stage of manually "booting" the whole system.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of potential solutions.

1. Put a manual high current battery switch between the multiplus and load so the caps are out of the circuit and don't need to be pre-charged. You would have to remember to turn on the switch when shore power is connected. But in that case, the caps should already be pre-charged by the shore power side of the circuit, so no inrush. If you make a mistake once and a while and cause inrush, hopefully it will not be catastrophic.
2. Never disconnect the battery from the multiplus except when you need to do maintenance. The caps will always be at the same voltage as the battery. No inrush.
3. Use a much smaller pre-charge resistor value to pre-charge much, much faster. It is probably the slow rise in voltage that is causing your DC-DC converter or radio to be unhappy.
4. Use a time delay relay before the DC-DC converter. It could possibly be activated by the 24 V on the multiplus side of the switch.
5. Design a circuit that either disables the DC-DC converter (if it has a logic input to disable it) or keeps power switched off (like a PMOS high-side FET to disconnect the DC-DC) until the multiplus voltage is over, say, 20 V.
6. Put a manual switch between the DC-DC converter. Turn it off when you do your pre-charge thing, then turn it back on after pre-charge is done. This is not automatic but it eliminates the relay.

That is all I can think of right now. There may be other ways to solve it. Keep in mind that relays always consume power when they are on (the coil consumes power when it is energized). If you have a tight power budget you would want to make sure the relay doesn't blow your budget.

Comment: Thanks! These are all good ideas. I decided to go with a version of  your #1 and #6 together, which I described in my own answer.